# Lightweight real time file reader?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io

Here is my problem (C#, .net3.5):

1. I basically need a file reader that reads files, which not yet but will be generated instantly, from a folder.
2. I know exactly what the name of those files gonna be.
3. I would like to read one file, process that file (some stats calculation), then move to next file when current processing is finished
4. Most importantly, I would like my file reader to be a light weight version, meaning consuming CPU resource as little as possible.

I would not think of using FileSystemWatcher, because:

1. When an event comes in (say, file ready) I am way behind processing the other file. Thus I will miss events if I rely on FileSystemWatcher.
2. Since files are going to be there anyway, and I know my file name exactly, I figure I can just go ahead read them if they are there.

Anyone has any suggestions? Right now I have tried FileSystemWatcher, and it skipped a lot of files. I also use a while(true) like look reading files until all files are taken care of, but it consumes 90% CPU.

Any suggestions is very appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the program whose output you're trying to read provide an API for that?

Comment: If the file is not there yet, will the reader keep reading?

Comment: Yes, but only if nobody is watching. What do you mean?

Comment: I think that is kinda what I did. The indefinitely loop consumed a lot of CPU. That is why I am seeking other solutions.

Comment: No you didn't. I'm talking about an API to read the generator's output, not the files it writes.

Comment: A little more information? Or better with an short example? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you don't understand me. I am asking _you_ to try things and provide information. You obviously are reading the output of some program. I am asking you if this program supplies a public API you can access, so you don't have to go through the hassle of reading its output files.

Comment: I don't think I have that access to API. Did I mention that in my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One suggestion: use file system watchers on multiple threads which pump files on a queue to be processed on other thread(s). If you still keep dropping files then you can increase the size of the FileSystemWatcher buffer, but this approach should work.

Comment: I set the buffer to 64K, but still, it dropped events. It is just it takes longer to drop the events.

Comment: @NickTsui: I think you misunderstood. The idea is to just put the file names into a `BlockingCollection<string>` or something similar, and have a separate thread removing the file names from the queue and processing them.

Comment: @JimMischel: OK correct me if I am wrong: so the BlockingCollection<string> is generated by the first thread? Meaning, every time there is a fileReady event coming in, the BlockingCollection<string> should be pushed in with a file name?

Comment: @NickTsui Correct, that's what Cal279 is suggesting. It's essentially a producer-consumer problem. (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem)

Comment: @vlad: Is that a producer-consumer problem? Because I see the producer can stop producing under the control of programmer in producer-consumer problem, whereas in my case the produce will keep producing regardless order from anyone. It seems to me they are fundamentally different.

Comment: @NickTsui I don't see how that makes a difference, for two reasons: 1.  you, as the programmer, can always tell the producer to stop producing (whether you want to or not is a different issue), and 2. even if you couldn't, that doesn't take away from the fact that you have one or more producers putting items in a queue, to be processed by consumers (which is the definition of the producer-consumer problem).

Comment: In this problem, my option is pretty much limited. It is not like "why don't you do this?", or "Can you try that?"; I wish I could have that much option too, really.

Answer (score -1):

My question would be, what is the rush that you have to have the files parsed instantly?

I would check the directory every x minutes or seconds for all files, put them in a queue and process them. Delete the files or rename them to a different extension if you want to keep them for some reason.

Check back in x time on a timer after the last file that was captured to see if there are new files.
Yes, you will get some to back up depending on your load, but I built a parser system that had hundreds of records a minute entered, and it worked fine and dandy using this method.

When there are no records to be parsed in that x amount of time the program gets a break until it checks the next interval. This is good because you can use this method to check multiple directories in a specific order as well for different processes.

Comment: Not worth the downvote. This is how its done in manufacturing high volume products that need to be tested and the results are automatically picked up by a parser like I explained.